# How to connect to a VLAN from a windows PC?

Tags: windows-7, vlan, iptv

There is IPTV service provided over VLAN 892 from my service provider. I have got set-top box from my ISP and I use it normally. But sometimes I wish to watch same TV channels from my windows 7 PC. I have the dhcp ID and password for IPTV service.

Can anybody suggest how to connect to that VLAN 892 where IPTV is provided on my windows PC?

Answer (score 2):

So far, the only options I know are:

- Recommended: Get a managed switch, and configure one port for the apropriate VLANs. (My old home gateway, running OpenRG, used to have very convenient configuration for this.)
- Install HyperV and use its virtual networks feature to create virtual interfaces that are bound to a specific VLAN. They'll be usable from the host too, even if you don't have any VMs. (Although, I think you'll need Windows 8 for this...)
- Some network card drivers have a VLAN setting in their device properties (in Device Manager); however, they usually only allow specifying one ID, unless you have server-grade NICs (and corresponding drivers).
- Use Linux, where it's literally just `ip link add link eth0 name eth0.892 type vlan id 892`. Probably not an option for a desktop, but it's an irreplaceable tool for me.